# Hybrid Mergesort and Insertion sort

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, mergesort, insertion-sort

I am trying to implement a hybrid of mergesort and insertion sort. When the subarray size reaches below a threshold, it should switch to insertion sort.
However I tried with a bunch of array of different length and different threshold amount, and most of the time there isn't any noticeable difference, other than just a 2-3 lesser comparisons. I was told that switching to insertion sort for smaller sized array would help greatly.

Am I doing it wrong?

```
#include <iostream>


int comparisons = 0;
int swaps = 0;

void mergesort(int x[], int l, int r);
void insertionSort(int x[],int start, int end);

int main() {
  int x[] = {9,5,1,4,3,10,29,69,5,9,11,19,21,69,0,2,3,4,5,11,111,96,25,32,21,2,12,3,52,55,23,32,15,15,14,13,9,5,1,4,3,10,29,69,5,9,11,19,21,69,0,2,3,4,5,11,111,96,25,32,21,2,12,3,52,55,23,32,15,15,14,13,};

  // insertionSort(x,10);
  int sizeX= sizeof(x)/sizeof(x[0]) ;
  mergesort(x, 0, sizeX-1);

  for(int i =0;i<sizeX;i++){
    std::cout << x[i] << " ";
  }
  // std::cout << "\nSWAPS: " << swaps;
  std::cout << "\nCOMPARISONS: " << comparisons;
}


void insertionSort(int arr[], int start,int end)
{
    int i, key, j;
    for (i = start +1 ; i < end; i++)
    {
        key = arr[i];
        j = i - 1;
 
        /* Move elements of arr[0..i-1], that are
        greater than key, to one position ahead
        of their current position */
        while (j >= 0 && arr[j] > key)
        {
            comparisons++;

            arr[j + 1] = arr[j];
            j = j - 1;
        }
        arr[j + 1] = key;
    }
}

void insertionSort2(int x[],int start, int end){
  for(int i =start; i < end;i++){
    for (int j= i; j!= 0;j--){
      comparisons++;

      if(x[j] < x[j-1]){
        int temp = x[j-1];
        x[j-1] = x[j];
        x[j] = temp;
        swaps++;
      }
      else{
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}


void mergesort(int x[], int l, int r) {
  if (l >= r)
    return;

  int mid = (l + r) / 2;

  if(r - l  < 3){
    insertionSort(x, l,r+1);
  }else{
    mergesort(x, l, mid);
    mergesort(x, mid + 1, r);

    int i = l; 
    int j = mid + 1; 
    int k = 0; 

    int tmp[r - l + 1];

    while (i <= mid && j <= r) {
      comparisons++;
      if (x[i] >= x[j]) {
        tmp[k] = x[j];
        j++;
      } else {
        tmp[k] = x[i];
        i++;
      }
      swaps++;
      k++;
    }

    while (i <= mid) {
      tmp[k] = x[i];
      i++;
      k++;
    }

    while (j <= r) {
      tmp[k] = x[j];
      j++;
      k++;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < k; i++) x[l + i] = tmp[i];
  }
}
```

Comment: *"However I tried with a bunch of array of different length and different threshold amount"* -- could you be more specific than "a bunch"? What are the smallest and largest threshold amounts you've tried? (I would expect very little difference with your current threshold of 3. With an array that short, even bubble sort performs well.)

Comment: I have tried with a few thousand elements that I generated randomly from a website, and trying from k 3 to 150, and mergesort did the best

Comment: *I have tried with a few thousand elements* -- That's hardly anything.  Also this: `int tmp[r - l + 1];` is not valid C++.  Arrays in C++ must have their size denoted by a compile-time expression, not a runtime computed value.  Use `std::vector` instead.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie how big of array should I be trying? Yes you are right, it's not valid C++. For some reason it compiles and run properly on replt

Comment: That is because the compiler you're using is using Variable Length Arrays, which are not part of standard C++.  If you compiled using the appropriate compiler switches, or if you simply used Visual C++, you will see your code fail to compile.

Comment: You also don't need a website to generate thousands of random numbers;  [see this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/48233e18181e5d68).

Comment: You need to test with much larger arrays, like 4 to 16 million elements, and set the threshold to switch to insertion sort to 32 or 64 elements. With pseudo-random data, it doesn't help much, it will end up about 10% faster.

Comment: I would switch to `std::vector`, call `generate` with the random number engine as in the example link.  Then you have your test data.  No need to go to a website -- you can then do your testing on various sizes very easily, simply by changing the initial size of the vector in the vector's constructor.

Comment: (Cross-posted to SO&[CS](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/143497/19966). Please give a community half a chance to provide a useful answer before involving another one.)